# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, subquery

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBoardGetByTeacherID]  
 @TeacherID int = NULL  
AS  
BEGIN  
        Select b.ID,b.[FullName],b.[Code],case when (Select BoardID from TeacherBoard where b.ID = BoardID and [TeacherID] = @TeacherID) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Selected    
    from Board b     
       where b.IsDeleted=0 and b.IsActive=1     
END
```

I created this stored procedure query to get list of Board and in that If Selected is 1 means checkbox is selected and if it is 0 checkbox is not selected but sometimes it gives me this error. where I had done wrong please give me proper solution for this

Comment: Apparently there's nothing preventing multiple rows with the same `BoardID` and `TeacherID ` values in `TeacherBoard`.

Comment: In your particular case you may use `... (Select MAX(BoardID) from ...`